# VB.net VS2015 Change font for entire project

Tags: vb.net, fonts, visual-studio-2015, controls

Is there an easy/quick way to change the font for all controls in a VB.net application? (Currently using VB 2015)

I mean all text boxes, buttons etc. It should be independent of the systems
default font.

Changing each control throughout the entire project (30-40 Forms+) would be extremely labor intensive.

Comment: Obviously editing the forms designer  files is a possibility, but im under the impression you should do that :)

Comment: Write an app to do it, you can go through the designer files and replace all the font properties...

Comment: There's nothing built into VS to do that.  You could write a VS extension and then it would be the quick and easy operation you want.

Comment: Font is an *ambient* property, it not explicitly set then it is the same as the parent.  You should almost always leave it ambient, only good way that a form rescales properly.  So all you have to do is change the Font property of the form, the rest of the controls follow suit.  Changing it 30 times is not the end of the world and not fundamentally different from changing these forms to use a new base class.  If you have any rescaling issues then you'll certainly see that back when you change the form's font.  Which does has a knack for turning 20 minutes in 20 days.

Answer (score 0):

## vb.net custom font

Even though I guess its not recommended to change default font family; sometimes its so needed, especially for accessibility, customization and personalization. This also can provide nice function for end user in some other applications.

> Thanks to many posts and answers and combining them; you can try to
>   change entire project's font family during run time.

- This is tested in VS 2017 CE , VB.Net 4.6.1; can't be sure for VS 2015.
- This answer also includes at the same time **applying google fonts without installing them into end user's OS**

**Steps to add custom fonts to VB.NET and Winforms:**

1. Grape a font from Google Fonts (Download as TTF).
2. Add the font into your solution.
3. Reference the new custom font and load it as an object.
4. Reference all controls in a form.
5. Check if the control accept/need font customization.
6. Apply the new font family.
7. Run and test.

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
Public Class Form1
    Dim pfc As New PrivateFontCollection()
    Private Function FindALLControlRecursive(ByVal list As List(Of Control), ByVal parent As Control) As List(Of Control)
        ' function that returns all control in a form, parent or child regardless of control's type
        If parent Is Nothing Then
            Return list
        Else
            list.Add(parent)
        End If
        For Each child As Control In parent.Controls
            FindALLControlRecursive(list, child)
        Next
        Return list
        End Functio
    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        ' On Form1 shown, start applying font 
        Dim CFontPath As String = Application.StartupPath
        pfc.AddFontFile(CFontPath & "\Resources\Fonts\Roboto.ttf")
        Dim allCtrl As New List(Of Control)
        For Each ctrl As Control In FindALLControlRecursive(allCtrl, Me)
            ' You need to define which control type to change it's font family; not recommendd to just change all controls' fonts, it will create a missy shape
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Label Or TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is Button Or TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is RadioButton Or TypeOf ctrl Is ProgressBar Or TypeOf ctrl Is GroupBox Or TypeOf ctrl Is Chart Then
                Dim CurrentCtrlFontSize = ctrl.Font.Size ' get current object's font size before applying new font family
                ctrl.Font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), CurrentCtrlFontSize, FontStyle.Regular)
            End If
        Next
        allCtrl.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can't be sure though this is the optimal code or best approach but it did the job and hope some collaboration.

*I know its an old date question but hope this answer helps and its very interesting question.*